# How to use Awswrangler inside a Glue Job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

For some reasons, I want to use the python package `awswrangler` inside a Python 3 Glue Job. There are two main ways I've considered for installing `awswrangler`:

- **Specify additional libraries to a glue job**. By considering `.whl` file and then passing it to the Glue Job through the `--extra-py-files`
- **Installing inside the python script with `subprocess` or `os`**. For example, the code example with `os` is the following

```
import os
os.system('python -m pip install --user awswrangler==0.0.b0')
```

Notice in the last case, that I've gone down to even use the first pre-release version of `awswrangler`. Full list of versions can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/awswrangler/0.0b6/#history). However, even with the first prelease I'm unable to use `awswrangler` on a Glue script. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried Glue 2.0? It supports packaging dependencies much better and you can make use of whl files

Comment: @Eman, I think Glue 2.0 currently only supports Spark Jobs, in this case is more a Machine Learning task, that's why I'm using the Python option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the official Awswrangler [Documentation](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#aws-glue-python-shell-jobs) provides you with a `.whl` file, that contains the desired version of the package, to specify on the `Python library path field` of the Glue Job. According to the documentation, the steps to follow are:

1. Download the `.whl` file related to the version that you want to install of `awswrangler` from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/releases).
2. Upload the `.whl` file to an s3 bucket, notice that the role you assign to your glue job should have access to read this bucket.
3. In the in the **Python library path** field specify the location of the wheel file. For example, for the current 1.9.3 version it is `s3://your-bucket/glue_wheels/awswrangler-1.9.3-py3-none-any.whl`

Answer (score 8):

Add the key/value below to the Glue Job parameters, it works for me for installing and using `awswrangler`.

Key: `--additional-python-modules`
Value: `pyarrow==2,awswrangler==2.4.0`

Comment: This worked when no other technique worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

use this it work for me

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call('pip3 install awswrangler -t /tmp/ --no-cache-dir'.split(), stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
sys.path.insert(1, '/tmp/')
```